# How to compare cls inside of a classmethod, in a class that works with many subclasses?

Tags: python, class, inheritance, subclass

I'm programming a calculator for civil engineering. It calculates a building properties based on user input (eg. height of the building) and material properties.

I'm using a bunch of subclasses to store the properties of individual materials. On top of them there's a class with classmethods, which are used for calculations that use material properties and user input.

HOWEVER a certain property (let's call it robustness) is calculated in two different ways, depending on which material is used. I want to have a **single** function to calculate the robustness for all materials.

My code looks as follows:

```
class Material:
    hardness = None
    density = None


    @classmethod
    def CalculateDurability(cls, userInput):
        if cls == '__main__.Concrete_1':
            output = cls.hardness * userInput
        else:
            output = cls.density * userInput
        print(output)



class Concrete_1(Material):
    hardness = 1
    density = 2


class Concrete_2(Material):
    hardness = 3
    density = 4


input = 1
Concrete_1.CalculateDurability(input)
Concrete_2.CalculateDurability(input)
```

The output is:

```
2
4
```

But it should be:

```
1
4
```

The problem clearly stems from here:

```
if cls == '__main__.Concrete_1':
```

This statement is always false.

So how can I get this comparison done correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use issubclass() built-in function, as follows:

```
@classmethod
def CalculateDurability(cls, userInput):
    if issubclass(cls,Concrete_1):
        output = cls.hardness * userInput
    else:
        output = cls.density * userInput
    print(output)
```